# SQL server Trigger no working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create this trigger, and this select:

```
SELECT @registro=seccion 
FROM dbo.horarios 
WHERE materia=@materia 
AND seccion=@seccionselect
```

is not working. [This link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/set-vs-select-assigning-variables.aspx)  states that: if the value is not returned from select, previous assign value will be kept. But the record matching this criteria is not found it is returning new data. In the bottom is the output and database values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_insertOnHorarios on horarios
 AFTER INSERT
 AS
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @materia varchar(7),@aula int,@profesor varchar(7), @seccion varchar(2),@dia varchar(10),
        @hora_desde time, @hora_hasta time, @cantidad int, @errores varchar(300), @displayError bit,@registro nchar(10)

   SELECT @materia= i.materia FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @profesor=i.profesor FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @seccion=i.seccion FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @dia= i.dia FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @hora_desde=i.hora_desde FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @hora_hasta= i.hora_hasta FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @cantidad= i.cantidad FROM inserted i;
   SELECT @aula = i.aula FROM inserted i;     
   IF  (SELECT cantidad_alumnos FROM aulas WHERE codigo=@aula)<@cantidad
   BEGIN 
            SET @errores= 'Contiene mas estudiantes de los permitidos en el aula,'
            PRINT @errores
            --RAISERROR (@errores,16,1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN 
    END

   print @seccion
   print @materia
   ***set @registro='empty'***
   print 'registro '+ @registro
   **SELECT @registro=seccion FROM dbo.horarios WHERE materia=@materia AND seccion=@seccion**   
   **print 'registro '+@registro**
   IF @registro = @seccion
   BEGIN                
            SET @errores= ' La seccion y la materia ya esta creada, por favor, haga una nueva seccion'
            PRINT @errores
            --RAISERROR (@errores,16,1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN 
    END       

       --------------------------------------------
      SELECT @registro=profesor FROM horarios WHERE dia=@dia AND hora_desde=@hora_desde AND @hora_hasta=hora_desde AND profesor=@profesor
       If @registro IS NOT NULL
       BEGIN                
            SET @errores=' el profesor ya esta asignado en este horario'
            PRINT @errores
            --RAISERROR (@errores,16,1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN 
       END
       --------------------------------------------
    declare @dayassig varchar(10),@desde time,@hasta time
   SELECT @registro=profesor, @dayassig=dia,@desde=hora_desde,@hasta=hora_hasta FROM horarios WHERE 
            @dayassig=@dia and
            ((@desde<=@hora_desde and @hasta>@hora_desde) OR
            (@desde<@hora_hasta and @hasta>=@hora_hasta))
       IF @registro IS NOT NULL        
       BEGIN
            SET @errores= @errores+' este horario choca'
            PRINT @errores
            --RAISERROR (@errores,16,1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN
       END   
END
```

**[output]**

```
03 (printing input on insert seccion)
CCI-110 (printing input on insert materia)
registro **empty**  (before select)   
registro **03**     (after select, should not be returning this)
La seccion y la materia ya esta creada, por favor, haga una nueva seccion
```

**[database values]**

```
materia aula profesor   seccion  dia      hora_desde        hora_hasta   cantidad
CCI-110 501  7722       01  miercoles   12:00:00.0000000    15:00:00.0000000    25
CCI-110 501  7722       01  miercoles   12:00:00.0000000    16:00:00.0000000    25
CCI-110 501  7722       01  miercoles   14:00:00.0000000    16:00:00.0000000    25
```

How you can see not record matching `input seccion 03` and`materia CCI-110`, but on `[output is printing on register 03]`?

Comment: Your trigger needs to handle multiple row operations. As it is coded it can't. Of course you really should populate all your variables at once instead of hitting the same table over and over. You also some serious logic issues going on. You have multiple rollback transaction statements. You have the possibility of getting to those more than once. The biggest question I have is what is the point of this trigger? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows. Each of your `SELECT @seccion=i.seccion FROM inserted i;` might be assigning values from different rows to your local variables. Try to write a *set* based solution that treats `inserted` as a *table*.

Comment: Now I realized I just express on bad way. the from insert select is  working as expect the problen is on the **SELECT @registro=seccion FROM dbo.horarios WHERE materia=@materia AND seccion=@seccion** , this select should not return new data, cuz on database theres not record matching those params from this insert:    INSERT into horarios VALUES ('CCI-110',501,'7722','03','miercoles','11:00:00','13:00:00',25), here im sending CCI-110 and 03 values, which not on database.

Comment: What im trying to achive is if not value found on database matching this two params should not get run codes on **IF statement**

Comment: @blinding you still appear not to be understanding what the previous comments are saying. Your trigger is only taking into account the case when only **one** row is inserted into your table.

Comment: Now i think I understand. Sorry. Multiple transcition if to break if one criteria is match and rollback everthing, no need to look beyond.  I have tested and realized that is inserting data then is comparing,but data is allready insert so if statement return true. I change after insert to for insert but still inserting data first. How can I first check if data exits and then insert.

Comment: @blinding Dude, the problem is that data exists, but probably **more than one row** got inserted and you are not taking that into account

Comment: yes, the problem was after insert, also try for update and nothig, cuz data was being inserted then I was comparing with the allready inserted data. I change type to instead of insert, so first i handle what I whant and then insert to the end if all conditions are satisfy. And with that it workss